# Easier Proof of $\sin{3\theta} + \sin\theta = 2\sin{2\theta}\cos\theta$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I am curious to see whether anybody can give me a proof that takes less steps.

Here is how I did it:

$$\sin{3\theta} + \sin\theta = 2\sin{2\theta}\cos\theta$$

LHS $$\eqalign{\sin(2\theta + \theta) + \sin\theta &= \sin2\theta\cos\theta + \cos2\theta\sin\theta + \sin\theta\\
&= \sin2\theta\cos\theta + (\cos^2\theta - \sin^2\theta)\sin\theta + \sin\theta\\
&= \sin2\theta\cos\theta + \sin\theta(\cos^2\theta - \sin^2\theta + 1)\\
&= \sin2\theta\cos\theta + \sin\theta(2\cos^2\theta)\\
&= \sin2\theta\cos\theta + 2\sin\theta\cos^2\theta\\
&= \sin2\theta\cos\theta + \cos\theta(\sin\theta\cos\theta + \sin\theta\cos\theta)\\
&= \sin2\theta\cos\theta + \cos\theta(\sin2\theta)\\ 
&= \sin2\theta\cos\theta + \cos\theta(\sin2\theta)\\
&= 2\sin2\theta\cos\theta.}$$

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the sum of angles identities for the $\sin$ function:- 
$$\sin(3\theta)=\sin(2\theta+\theta)=\sin(2\theta)\cos(\theta)+\cos(2\theta)\sin(\theta)$$
$$\sin(\theta)=\sin(2\theta-\theta)=\sin(2\theta)\cos(\theta)-\cos(2\theta)\sin(\theta)$$

Adding both equations results in
$$\sin(3\theta)+\sin(\theta)=2\sin(2\theta)\cos(\theta)$$

Comment: Great, this is the kind of thing I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

Use the trigonometric identity about $\sin A + \sin B= 2\sin \frac{A+B}{2} \cos\frac{A-B}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can differentiate both sides and check whether they are equal: $$\eqalign{
\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\theta}\big[\sin3\theta+\sin\theta\big]&\overset?=\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\theta}\big[2\sin2\theta\cos\theta\big] \\
3\cos3\theta+\cos\theta&\overset?= 2\big[\tfrac12( \cos\theta+3\cos3\theta)\big]\tag{$\overset{\rm Chain}{\underset{\sf rule}{}}\overset{\,+}{}\overset{\rm Prod.}{\underset{\sf rule}{}}$}\\
3\cos3\theta+\cos\theta&\overset?= \cos\theta+3\cos3\theta. \quad\checkmark
}$$
So you can conclude that they're the same. [image: ;-)]

Comment: To be precise, from that you deduce that they differ by a constant, but that constant can be simply determined by evaluating at a point.

Comment: @Dario Yes my proof wasn't complete, I leaved it to Midni.

Comment: I plan on studying calculus after finishing this pre-calculus material which this is part of. So I will thank you after I understand what your solution means haha. I like your blog, you seem quite interesting ;)

Comment: @Midni Haha many thanks for your very kind words!  $\overset{\cdot\cdot}\smile$ $\color{white}{\text{even if I didn't update the blog for a long time ^^}}$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin(3\theta)+\sin(\theta)=\Im[e^{3i\theta}]+\Im[e^{i\theta}]=\Im[e^{3i\theta}+e^{i\theta}]=$$
$$=\Im[e^{2i\theta}(e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta})]=2\cos(\theta)\Im[e^{2i\theta}]=2\cos(\theta)\sin(2\theta)\ .$$

Comment: I forgot to mention in my post that it should be done using only elementary trigonometric identities(hence me having no idea what your solution means haha). Thank you for your post nonetheless.

Comment: I suppose this approach is not required at all after the proofs presented above.